# Handling unusual network events in Java (UDP)

Tags: java, network-programming

I've some doubts related to *DatagramChannel*. I've just made a quick test with unplugging cable when socket is bound and receive method is running in blocking mode in the background. There was no exception thrown, even when I wrote to this socket. 
After again plugging in cable everything looks fine - socket was still bound. 
Some questions raised after this test:

1) When there is a need to rebind the socket ? (some scenarios with system or network events)

2) Will be any exception thrown when network is unreachable? (When I'm writing to a socket which is bound on unreachable interface, will packet be buffered in cache and wait for interface to be up)

3) When channel for socket could be closed by system ?

Thanks in advance. Do you know any book related to this kind of topic (low level details)?

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat implementation independent. When the cable was disconnected, the OS may have possibly detected a failure of the medium and invalidated all sockets, but this *did not occur here*. It may not even be truly valid for a UDP-like protocol.

> There was no exception thrown even when I wrote to this socket.

Even if you write to a socket connected to a black hole over UDP, you don't care. As long as there's space in send buffers and the packet to be sent is valid(as in size, addressing), there will be no error even if it gets mangled by routers or lost along the way. Here, it just got lost pretty close to the origin.

> 2) Will be any exception thrown when network is unreachable? (When I'm writing to a socket which is bound on unreachable interface, will packet be buffered in cache and wait for interface to be up)

Generally, it is in the spirit of UDP to just send the packet without regard to how far it will make it before being lost.

> 3) When channel for socket could be closed by system ?

when it's not a connectionless protocol. If this were TCP you'd detect a lack of keepalive packets and a general breakage of communication and the channel would be broken.

Comment: Once you open a connection I believe it stays open until you close it yourself, despite there being a disconnected cable.  The router may try to resend it a few times, but then it'll probably just throw the packets away.

Comment: @aglassman If the cable is unplugged at the machine there won't be a router, just an IP stack.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) When there is a need to rebind the socket ? (some scenarios with system or network events)

You can't rebind a socket.

> 2) Will be any exception thrown when network is unreachable?

You won't get an exceptions sending UDP datagrams unless the socket is connected to the destination, when you can get 'unreachable' errors.

> (When I'm writing to a socket which is bound on unreachable interface, will packet be buffered in cache and wait for interface to be up)

No.

> 3) When channel for socket could be closed by system ?

Never. You have to close it yourself.

> Do you know any book related to this kind of topic (low level details)?

For this kind of detail you would have to go to the oracle, W. Richard Stevens, *TCP/IP Illustrated,* volumes I and II.